# How to load multiple page(cshtml) inside single page on button click with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ngroute

I am creating crud operation in Angular.js with mvc with have following pages:

- Index:This is the main page under which I want to display my list of employee page i.e _employeeList.cshtml.
- AddNewEmployee.cshtml:This page will be used for creating new employee
- EditEmployee.cshtml:For opening record in edit mode for particular employee.

All this pages I want to render inside Index.cshtml page i.e to create single page application.

When my page loads I want to display list of employees and when user clicks on Add Employee then I want to open new add employee page.

This is  my current code:

**Layout.cshmtl**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="empApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1 style="margin-left:750px;">
    List
</h1>


<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="AddEmployee()" value="Add Employee">
<div ng-controller="employeeListCtrl">
    @Html.Partial("_employeeList")
</div>

<script src="~/AppScript/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/AppScript/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/AppScript/Employee.js"></script>
```

**Module.js:**

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("empApp", [])
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('')
        {

        }
    });
})();
```

So basically I am stuck here. When user will click on `Add Employee` button, how I will load my `AddNewEmployee.cshtml` page in current index.cshtml page without page refresh?

**Update:**

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<h1 style="margin-left:750px;">
    List
</h1>


<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="AddEmployee()" value="Add Employee">
@*<div ng-controller="employeeListCtrl">
    @Html.Partial("_employeeList")
</div>*@

<ng-view></ng-view>


<script src="~/AppScript/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/AppScript/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/AppScript/EmployeeListController.js"></script>
```

**Module.js**:

```
var app = angular.module("empApp", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/employeelist',
        {
            templateUrl: 'Views/Home/_employeeList.cshtml',
            controller: 'employeeListCtrl'

        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
    });
```

**EmployeeListController:**

```
app.controller('employeeListCtrl', function ($scope, crudService) {
    alert()
});
```

But here my EmployeeListController doesnt gets called when my url is like this  as shown in below pic and when I run my application why my url is like this as shown in below pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function in controller like

```
$scope.AddEmployee = function()
{
$location.url("AddNewEmployee");
}
```

After this you can check condition in config like

```
.when("/AddNewEmployee",{
  templateUrl : "AddNewEmployee.cshtml",
controller : ""
})
```

Comment: In 1 link I have studied that you can directly render .cshtml file and so you have to call like this from controller to view